# Scala lambda only failing in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, sbt

Im writing my first scala lambda, and locally everything connects and works fine.  However, when I try to test my lambda in AWS, I get the following error.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Error loading class FooBar.Main: scala/collection/Seq",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"
}
```

From my googling, its seems this is cause I needed to add the scala library to my dependencies, which I did.

```
name := "FooBar"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.12"
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-Xlint")
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
settings(
  name := "FooBar",
  version := "1.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.12",
  retrieveManaged := true
)
libraryDependencies += "software.amazon.awssdk" % "ec2" % "2.5.60"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-events" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-dynamodb" % "1.11.313"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc" % "3.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-core" % "4.14.3-HBase-1.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.4.10"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.4.10"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.12.12"

assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.keep("x.**").inAll,
  ShadeRule.keep("FooBar.**").inProject
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

again, everything works fine locally, just can never execute on AWS.  Anyone have an idea?

Comment: what is the command you are using to build the jar?

Comment: deleted my previous comment, sbt assembly is used in both scripts and manually.

Comment: assemblyShadeRules looks suspicious. What exactly are you trying to achieve with them?

Comment: I'm trying to keep down the size of the jar file.  Using both the Dynamo and Phoenix libraries make it to large for AWS otherwise.

Comment: So I unzipped my jar, and with the shadeRule in place, a scala folder doesn't show up.  It is there if i remove the shadeRule, but then my jar is to large for AWS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sbt-assembly plugins shade rule `ShadeRule.keep` documentation states

> The ShadeRule.keep rule marks all matched classes as "roots". If any
> keep rules are defined all classes which are not reachable from the
> roots via dependency analysis are discarded when writing the output
> jar.

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading

So in this case all the classes of the class path `x.*` and `FooBar.*` are retained while creating the fat jar. Rest all other classes including the classes in scala-library are discarded.

To fix this remove all the `ShadeRule.keep` rules and instead try `ShadeRule.zap` to selectively discard classes not required.

For example, the following shade rules removes all the HDFS classes from the far jar:

```
  assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
    ShadeRule.zap("org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.**").inAll
  )
```

PS: AWS Lambda had a hard limit of 256MB of code size *after* unzipping the fat jar.

Comment: I seem to still be having some issues with this.  As an example, I want to remove everything under "com.ibm"  I have tried the following varitions:
  ShadeRule.zap("com.ibm*").inAll,
  ShadeRule.zap("com.ibm.*").inAll,
  ShadeRule.zap("com.ibm.**").inAll

it doesn't error, but it doesn't remove anything either